# Codeigniter 'required' validation throws error even on valid inputs

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, validation

---

I have a simple form where input field for mobile number was given to user, on submit it checks for validation through validation rules, however despite having pre-filled value in input tag, the required field error being thrown.

```
[$this->form_validation->set_rules('mobile','Mobile','trim|required|numeric|exact_length\[10\]|callback_checkMobile');][1]
```

---

```
public function checkMobile($number){
if ($e_name=$this->HomeModel->isDuplicateMobile($number)) {
  if ($this->session->userdata('admin_name')) {
    if ($e_name!=$this->session->userdata('admin_name')) {
      $this->form_validation->set_message('checkMobile','The {field} Number already registered to '.$e_name.'.');
      return false;
    }
  } elseif ($this->session->userdata('user_name')) {
    if ($e_name!=$this->session->userdata('user_name')) {
      $this->form_validation->set_message('checkMobile','The {field} Number already registered to '.$e_name.'.');
      return false;
    }
  }

} else {
  return true;
}
```

}

---

```
<input class="<?=(form_error('mobile'))?'is-invalid':'is-valid'?> form-control" type="text" name="mobile" value="<?=set_value('mobile',$e_mobile)?>">
```

Comment: There is a `;` in the first line between the square brackets. Also I see you use the php shortcode, that could cause problems as well. Fix those first and try again

Comment: Posting full validation code may helpful.

Comment: I am a new user, I could not update the code after posting it so that semi-colon was mistaken by the editor while posting the code. there is no error on that line I re-checked with multiple other fields values, the problem caused only in callback_functions

Answer (score 0):

Use this one "is_unique"

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('mobile','Mobile','trim|required|numeric|is_unique[table.fieldName]');
```

or

```
if($this->input->post('mobile') != $original_value) {
   $is_unique =  '|is_unique[table.fieldName]'
} else {
   $is_unique =  ''
}

$this->form_validation->set_rules('user_name', 'User Name', 'required|trim|xss_clean'.$is_unique);
```

Comment: In case of profile updation if I use is_unique it throws error since the same details are already available in database (although it is the same user who is updating itself), so there is no use of is_unique in this case. I tried it as well. Thanks for help but still suffering.

Comment: Your code works however I came to know that callback functions are not being called with list of validation rules, if I make only callback function call request it works but I had to make my own validation rules in that function, still don't know why i can not combine validation rules with callback_function.